# Programmatically access Websphere Application Server and its resources

Tags: websphere, jmx

This is my very first question on StackOverflow so, please bear with me.

What am I trying to achieve?

I need to write a standalone program to access a particular instance or multiple instances of Websphere Application Server and get details from it.  As far as my research goes, there are two ways to do this.

1. Adaptors
2. Connectors

I am currently taking up the 'Connectors' approach and that too the SOAP connector (for its firewall friendliness)

So, my code would be something like this..

---

```
// Initialize the AdminClient.
Properties adminProps = new Properties();

adminProps.setProperty("type", AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP );
adminProps.setProperty("host", "localhost");
adminProps.setProperty("port", "8880");
AdminClient adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(adminProps);

String query = "WebSphere:*";
//String query = "WebSphere:type=Server,*";
ObjectName queryName = new ObjectName(query);
Set s = adminClient.queryNames(queryName, null);
if (!s.isEmpty()) {
    iter = s.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        ObjectName nodeagent = (ObjectName) iter.next();
    System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("KeyPropertyList: " + nodeagent.getKeyPropertyListString());
    }
}
```

---

With this piece of code, I am able to get the list of all the MBeans on that particular instance of the WAS (C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01) and it successfully prints the Key - Property list.

Now I have a list of MBeans.  What next?
Link: _http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/index.html

Here is my query:

How do I get an instance of a particular MBean I am interested in and fetch all related properties?

For example:

```
AppManagement appM = AppManagementProxy.getJMXProxyForClient (adminClient);
System.out.println(appM.listApplications(null, null, null));
```

Would list all the application(s) on that particular instance of WAS

[query, SamplesGallery, ivtApp, DefaultApplication, PlantsByWebSphere]

I am interested in knowing more about the applications installed say, are they up and running? If so, the IP Address, build number, is it in maintenance, etc., (just quoting them as an example)  If I can get all possible details of the application that the MBean could offer, then it would complete my task (partly)

The aforementioned is just an example and I would like to get more out of MBeans.  So, please provide a solution / sample code that would help me out in getting information from any MBean the WAS instance has to offer. (Using JMX)

Additional Details:
IBM WebSphere Application Server, 7.0.0.0 (Base Installation)

Thanks in Advance,
AJ

Answer (score 1):

IP address you could get indirectly by querying all servers and checking if the app is running on each of them, and then finding getting the host from each server.  I'm not sure if build number is available.  What does "in maintenance" mean?

You can get more information from the Application and J2EEApplication (JSR 88) MBeans.  So, ObjectName("WebSphere:type=Application,name=myapp"), which is WebSphere-specific, or ObjectName("WebSphere:type=J2EEApplication,name=myapp").

You can get configuration information using ConfigServiceProxy and querying for the getid("/DefaultApplication:myapp/").  You can look at PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/CELL/applications/APP.ear/deployments/APP/deployment.xml to see the kind of information available from the config.  You can match it up with the type information in WAS_HOME/web/configDocs/ starting with the appdeployment package.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  By 'in maintenance', I mean that the application may be down during maintenance.  So, when it is down, it cannot probably get data from it.  Anyways, ConfigServiceProxy can be used for the MBeans of the type ConfigService (correct me if I am wrong).  Where can I find a more comprehensive list of ways to access MBeans and whether we have proxies like the ones mentioned here(AppManagementProxy,ConfigServiceProxy) or do we have to rely on the cumbersome and error prone AdminClient.invoke(ObjectName,operation,params,signature); method?

Comment: Yes, ConfigServiceProxy allows access to ConfigService, which is an MBean for navigating all WAS configuration.  I'm not sure if there's a comprehensive list of proxies.  I would say it's a good idea to write your own just to avoid cluttering your main logic with MBean interaction.

Comment: Thanks again for such a quick response.. This is something that I am doing for the very first time.  So, can you please direct me to a tutorial to write my own proxy?  Is it something like a Helper that we are going to write in the end? something like MBeanHelper.getServerMbeans? (MBeanHelper class written by us)

Comment: Simply write a helper class that has an AdminClient instance variable, and then add methods as needed that delegate to AdminClient.invoke(ObjectName, op, params, sig).  That's all that the pre-supplied proxies do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String query = "WebSphere:*,mbeanIdentifier=<XXX>";
```

Where  is the identifier of the mbean